# Flask-WTF form has errors during GET request

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have a Flask view with a Flask-WTF form. When I load the page in the browser, the form always has errors, even though I haven't submitted it yet. Why does the form have errors before it is submitted?

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = ApplicationForm(request.form)

    if form.is_submitted():
        print "Form successfully submitted"

    if form.validate():
        print "valid"

    print(form.errors)  

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect('index')

    return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

```
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Nov/2016 16:54:12] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
{'department': [u'Not a valid choice'], 'email': [u'This field is required.'], 'csrf_token': ['CSRF token missing'], 'name': [u'This field is required.'], 'address': [u'This field is required.']}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a get request, so `request.form` is empty. You're calling `validate` unconditionally, so you're validating against empty data. Therefore, everything's invalid. This is why `validate_on_submit` exists: it doesn't validate for get requests, since they don't have form data.

Remove the `if form.validate()` block.

`form.errors` is only populated after validation, so move it below the `validate_on_submit` block or it will always appear empty.

---

Also, you don't need to pass `request.form`, Flask-WTF will automatically pass it if the form is submitted.